# Typescript match a specific key to be the same value for two generic objects that may be different

Tags: typescript

There's a stange behaviour of typescript that I can't explain.

What I want to achieve is that I have a function like so:

```
function getDbRowFromRow<T, Key extends keyof T, R extends Pick<T, Key>>(
  dbRow: T[],
  key: Key,
  row: R)
{
  const map = new Map<T[Key], T>(dbRows.map(r => [r[key], r]));

  // the key throws the type error here
  map.get(row[key]);
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQCICMBKcDuAYgE5wC2e+APACoA0iA0qgJ6KoAeUqYAJgM6IA1qzjBE9RDnZceAxAAUYEIbQbMWAPk0AKAFCJEvXAX4AuCQG0AunQPDWFjXcOl8FnAEo9Ab3sQEfihEMgBDAAdEAF5EMFR8RABZCNpLDVsJXWNKfgA6MPCdYmjNREtiSxEWDOJrT08Abj17AHoWxCgAC1QHNi63QS6eqBZwntRiUmLu4lR7Aty0KCKCStY6poBfIA

This error is thrown:

```
Argument of type 'R[Key]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T[Key]'.
Type 'R' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'R'.
```

Now I don't quite understand where anything could be broken, because clearly if the R extends  Pick<T, Key> then that part of the two generic objects must be the same.

Another clue is that even if I try to `as T[Key]` the row, it gives me the usual cast first to `unknown` error. So it thinks the types are not even marginally related.

So what am I missing? Is there some way I could truly violate that type constraint or is this just a weird typescript quirk?

If it's needed I'll post the actual problem that is to be solved, I just thought a minimal example would be more clear.

Comment: I think the issue is that the compiler is concerned about the rest of the keys in `T`/`R` and doesn't realize that you will only be looking at the `Key` key.  Essentially it lacks the sort of higher order analysis abilities to recognize `(Pick<T, K> & Omit<U, K>)[K]` and `T[K]` to be identical types for generic `T` and `K`.  Luckily since `R extends Pick<T, Key>` you can widen a value of type `R` to `Pick<T, K>` before you index into it as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N5xy2w). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That is absolutely amazing that you can't cast the end result but you can cast to Pick<T, K> first and then it just works out. Most typesafe way to do it I guess due to the compiler not being able to do this transformation on it's own. This is as good as an answer for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDbRowFromRow<T, Key extends keyof T> (
  dbRows: T[],
  key: Key,
  row: Pick<T, Key>) // <- you don't need the whole new generic arg here
{
  const map /* : Map<T[Key], T> */ = new Map(dbRows.map(r => [r[key], r]));
  map.get(row[key]);
}
```

Comment: The original versions has an additional constraint on the row that it has to have a start & end date for after the map.get(). Unfortunately if I add anything after the Pick it just doesn't accept it anymore. Eg. `Pick<T, Key> & { a: number }`. Would already fail. I agree the generic for row is sort of an overkill and I should have known better.

Comment: Then that should also be a constraint on T?

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript compiler isn't really able to do arbitrary analysis on combinations of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters, their [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) and [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  It's able to do *some* of that, but only to some extent.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884) for the kind of limitation I'm talking about, although it's not 100% the same as this.)

You have `R extends Pick<T, K>` and therefore we can think of `R` as something like `Pick<T, K> & U` for some other type `U`.  And you want the compiler to recognize that `(Pick<T, K> & U)[K]` is assignable to `T[K]`.  This is almost certainly true (I can't think of a way it could be false), but the compiler can't see it.  On the other hand, it *can* see that `Pick<T, K>[K]` is assignable to `T[K]`.  The part that confuses it is that `R` is some arbitrary subtype of `Pick<T, K>`.

That means we can work around the issue by widening a value of type `R` to type `Pick<T, K>` which is type safe (as much as anything is in TypeScript) before indexing into it:

```
function getDbRowFromRow<T, K extends keyof T, R extends Pick<T, K>>(
  dbRows: T[], key: K, row: R) {
  const map = new Map<T[K], T>(dbRows.map(r => [r[key], r]));
  const r: Pick<T, K> = row; // okay
  map.get(r[key]); // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQCICMBKcDuAYgE5wC2e+APACoA0iA0oqgB5SpgAmAzogNaoAnnGCJ6iHC3adeiAAowI-Wg0YA+dQAoAUIkRdcBHgC5xAbQC6DQULOMGpfGZwBKRAG89iCAh5REMgBDAAdEAF5EMFR8RABZUNpzRmtxbUNKHgA6YJCtYgj1RHNic1tU4ktXVwBub18wf0RiM0VlVSYiyKcaxAB6PsQ4fiChb1ystCh8suEq3oGhkbGAXyA)